# Disable zoom on specific HTML widget without using meta tags

Tags: html, css, viewport

I'm developing an HTML widget that will be deployed on a client's mobile site. When activated the widget must take up 100% of the screen at all times. The problem I'm running into is that the widget isn't always 100% of the screen due to the user being able to zoom. I'm unable to changed the meta tag (see below) for zooming because the client allows zooming outside of the widget.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I have a feeling that I could probably iFrame the widget content, set the meta tag there, and be isolated from the rest of the site, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution.

**TL;DR: What's the best solution for disallowing zoom on a specific HTML container?**

Answer (score 0):

You would use [hammer.js](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started) to detect a "pinch zoom" gesture, and the library gives you a very detailed event.gesture object which you can use to detect how much/how fast the user is zooming. After you connect hammer.js, you can disable zoom with:

```
behavior:
    contentZooming: "none"
```